# How do I add a highscore system to my game?

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a highscore system into my skeet shooting game. This all runs in the console. I need the game to save the highscore with the player's name, so I am assuming I need to put them into an array. I am not sure how to go about adding the scores and names to an array in my current code, though.

```
public class Target {

public static int score = 0;
public static int i = 0;
public static String gameStart;

    public void TargetInfo(Player l) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Loop for all 25 targets
        for(i=0; i<25; i++) {

        System.out.println("\nhit Enter to shoot");
        gameStart = scan.nextLine();

        if(gameStart.equals("")){

            int random1 = (int) (Math.random() * 105 + 15);

        //Distance 15-35ft
        if (random1 >= 15 && random1 <= 35) {

            System.out.println("Your target is " + random1 + "ft away");

            int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);

            if(random2<=3) {

                score++;
                System.out.println("You got one!");
            }
            else{

                System.out.println("You missed");
            }

        }
            //Distance 36-75ft
            else if (random1 >=36 && random1 <=75) {

                System.out.println("Your target is " + random1 + "ft away");

                int random3 = (int) (Math.random() * 21 + 1);

                if (random3 <= 11) {

                    score++;
                    System.out.println("You got one!");
                }
                else{

                    System.out.println("You missed");
                }

            }
            //Target Distance 76-105ft
            else if (random1 >=76 && random1 <=105){

                System.out.println("Your target is " + random1 + "ft away");

                int random4 = (int) (Math.random() * 11 + 1);

                    if (random4 <= 2) {

                        score++;
                        System.out.println("You got one!");
                    }
                        else{

                            System.out.println("You missed");
                }

            }

    }
}

        System.out.println(l.name + ", your score is: " + score);


    }
```

}

Comment: Save the high scores to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this any number of ways, like adding an array of ints and an array of names, or a Hashtable. Personally, I prefer this way:

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> highScores = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
```

This way you could associate scores with particular players. This would be easier than maintaining an index for each array.

At the end of every game, check whether or not the current score is higher than at least the lowest high score in your Hashtable, then you can update it. [Here's the documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)